# Which US states have criminalized hitchhiking?

Tags: usa, legal, hitchhiking

Are there U.S. states where it is illegal to hitchhike? I have looked around and have not found any site which has substantiated their claims with up to date sources.

Comment: As a reminder, one of the expectations of StackExchange is that you demonstrate some initial research effort. For instance, a simple Google search on "hitchhiking legal us" turns up a [Hitchwiki](http://hitchwiki.org/en/United_States_of_America), [blogs](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2012/06/04/travel-like-your-grandfather-how-to-hitchhike-around-the-usa/) of [various](https://expertvagabond.com/hitchhiking-america/) sorts, and even a [legal information site](https://www.hg.org/article.asp?id=31488) page on the matter.

Comment: @choster: many of those sites have unsubstantiated, unsourced, or out-of-date information. Hitchwiki has the information, but buried throughout the website. I compiled all the sourced information all in one place, which I argue is useful.

Comment: You should cite your research and describe why those findings are inadequate. Otherwise, answerers will waste time providing answers based on those easily available sources. This is basic SE courtesy.

Comment: @choster: Please note that crypdick answered his/her own question a few seconds before your first comment. It's very difficult to show just the right amount of research in a self-answered question -- too little, and it's not clear why the question merits a post here; too much, and the answer itself will be in the question. I think we can cut crypdick a bit of slack if (s)he didn't strike quite the right balance.

Comment: @crypdick: Note that there is an option when asking a question to post an answer *simultaneously*. It isn't clear here whether you used it or not, but from the reaction of choster it seems you didn't and this created some drama. If you wish to self-answer, I encourage you to use it. Also note that it doesn't dispense from creating a well-formulated question (and yes, it's not easy to balance how much to put in the question...).

Comment: FWIW I live in Seattle, Washington (a state that is green on the [colored map answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/88943/9463)) and I see signs everywhere prohibiting hitchhiking (which, afaik, are actively enforced). While there might not be an official law, it can be difficult for other reasons.

Comment: OP and @Frank: as well as state laws, there are **local laws** (city and county. But currently the question only asks about **state laws**.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It varies from state to state.

[image]

Some are legal for it to be done on the shoulder of the road. (green)

Others off the travelled part of the road (eg stand in grass). (yellow)

Others - completely illegal. (red)

Others - unclear. (grey)

There's a map and guide on [Hitchwiki](http://hitchwiki.org/en/File:Unitedstateslaws.jpg) indicating the status for each one.  This comes from the main [USA page on Hitchwiki](http://hitchwiki.org/en/United_States_of_America).

Comment: In green states, it's wise to look for "No hitchhiking" signs, which in some states tend to be posted in places where it could commonly interfere with traffic, particularly freeway on-ramps.

Comment: In 20 years in California, I have never seen a hitchhiker.  Don't count on getting picked up any time soon.

Comment: @Malvolio have hitched in Cali :) In Los Angeles even. Although this was 16 years ago.

Answer (score 22):

## Delaware

Source: [DEL CODE § 4147](http://www.delcode.delaware.gov/title21/c041/sc05/index.shtml)

## New Jersey

Source: [39:4-59](http://www.njlaws.com/39-4-59.html)

## Nevada

Source: [NRS 484B.297](http://www.leg.state.nv.us/nrs/NRS-484B.html#NRS484BSec297)

## Idaho

Source: [49-709](https://legislature.idaho.gov/statutesrules/idstat/Title49/T49CH7/SECT49-709/)

## Utah

Source: [41_04117](http://law.justia.com/codes/utah/2006/title41/41_04117.html)

Note: federal laws supersede state laws, and the federal law states that the legality of hitchhiking within national parks is decided by the superintendent of that park (Source: [CFR Title 36 section 4.31](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2001-title36-vol1/pdf/CFR-2001-title36-vol1-sec4-31.pdf)).

Credit: All the hard work was done by [Hitchwiki](http://hitchwiki.org/), I just compiled all the references in one place.

Comment: Looking at the map provided by @MarkMayo, it seems Delaware should also have a provision outlawing it.

Comment: Federal laws supersede state laws *under certain conditions*.  The full rules for which laws supersede which is complicated, and probably worthy of a whole series of questions on Law.SE.

Comment: Doesn't it just say hitchhiking is illegal on highways?
I would think it was easier to catch a ride at a gas station anyway.

Comment: Good catch @KRyan, I've added Delaware